# Пытаюсь через скрипты на Python подключиться к бд Oracle

Tags: python, база-данных, oracle

Выдаёт такую ошибку: module not found error: no module named cx_oracle. Подскажите, как решить?
Прописал пути переменных как в Инете советовали: 
в Переменная среды пользователя:

> PATH - C:\Users\USER\Documents\Borland Studio
>   Projects\Bpl;C:\Users\USER\Downloads\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_19_3

и в Системные переменные:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Borland\BDS\4.0\Bin;C:\oracle\instantclient-basic\instantclient_19_3;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Borland\CaliberRM SDK 2005 R2\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\USER\Downloads\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_19_3

НЕ ПОМОГЛО.

Comment: скачать этот модуль, скорее всего у вас написано `import cx_oracle` где то. Смотрите команду `pip install`

Comment: какой модуль скачать?

Comment: Скачал. Прописал переменные. Не помогло. Что за pip install?

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ на en so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307479/install-cx-oracle-for-python/4309403

Comment: Посмотрел. Ничего интересного. Там Линукс, а мне надо на винде. И в принципе всё то же самое, что я уже делал.

Answer (score 1):

вот нашел на qaru.site

Поддержка Windows и Anaconda

Anaconda 4.3.0 поставляется с Python 3.6 в качестве корня. В настоящее время cx_Oracle поддерживает только до 3.5. Я попытался создать среду 3.5 в envs, но при запуске cx_Oracle-5.2.1-11g.win-amd64-py3.5.exe она устанавливается в корне только с 3,6

Только обходной путь, который я мог найти, - изменить корневую среду с 3.6 до 3.5:

```
activate root
conda update --all python=3.5
```

Когда это завершает работу cx_Oracle-5.2.1-11g.win-amd64-py3.5.exe.

Протестировал его с помощью импорта и работал отлично.

```
import CX_Oracle
```

Comment: А делать-то Что нужно чтобы заработало?

Answer (score 0):

Если при запуске того `Python` в который ставили библиотеку, вы прописывая `import cx_Oracle` получаете `import error`, значит вы его поставили куда-то в др. место или не поставили.
Проверяйте куда вы установили библиотеку и не было ли там ошибок. При нормальной установке в папке вашего питона в Lib/site-packages - должен быть файл `cx_Oracle.pyd`

Comment: Хоть какой-то конкретный пример установки этого  модуля есть?